# How to order class and interface together by resharper custom layout?

Tags: resharper

For example interfaces and classes are like below.

```
public class Foo1 : IFoo1 {}
public class Foo2 : IFoo2 {}
public class Foo3 : IFoo3 {}
public interface IFoo1 {}
public interface IFoo2 {}
public interface IFoo3 {}

I would like them to order like below.

#region Foo1

public interface IFoo1 {}
public class Foo1 : IFoo1 {}

#endregion

#region Foo2

public interface IFoo2 {}
public class Foo2 : IFoo2 {}

#endregion

#region Foo3

public interface IFoo3 {}
public class Foo3 : IFoo3 {}

#endregion
```

Is such a thing possible ?

If it is not possible;

```
public interface ITest {}
public class Test : ITest {}
```

May it be like that ? First interface then class.

Comment: It's usually best practice to put Interfaces and Classes into their own individual files then this ordering wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You're right but putting interfaces and classes into their own individual files doesn't make sense for me when there is too much file. I can get lost among files.

Comment: How many Classes/Interfaces are you dealing with? Resharper makes it extremely easy to extract them all into their own files and finding them again is no problem by using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`T` (Go to file)

Comment: I know that. About 50 files. I prefer to use `CTRL` + `T` for searching in types. Tree list becomes too long when I use solution explorer, and I don't like that.